# How to find a ListView in a DataTemplate?

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have this ListView  in xaml

```
    <ListView x:Name="PersonsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource personLayout}">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="personLayout" DataType="Person">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
                <ListView x:Name="AddressesListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Addresses}"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

How can I use AddressesListView in code behind? 
For instance if I want to do AddressesListView.SelecItem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Chk out this blog post for more scenarios like this.....

[http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/03/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-i.aspx](http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-i.aspx)

http://blogs.msdn.com/wpfsdk/archive/2007/04/16/how-do-i-programmatically-interact-with-template-generated-elements-part-ii.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Given an item in the PersonsListView that is of Type Person, you can use the ItemContainerGenerator property on the PersonsListView, and find the container for the data item. You should then bable to use FrameworkElement.FindName(), to find that specific element.

The nested listview looks kinda weird BTW :)

Comment: My statement about listviews containing other list views being odd? Sure -- it's just odd to see lists inside other lists... at least using full on list view controls (eg having N levels of selection). Just seems odd.

Comment: Thanks!. I have an insight and realize I was mixing in a DataTemplate data & views. soy un nabo.